# C ++ Find highest value in array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that allows the user to enter 10 values, and then displays the highest value in the array. Everytime I run the program, it gives me an error saying the stack was corrupted. Help please? this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
const int SIZE = 10;
int number[SIZE];
int count;
int highest;

for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter 10 numbers" << endl;
    cin >> number[SIZE];
}

for (count =1; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    if (number[count] > highest)
        highest = number[count];
}

cout << highest << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to C++. I'd like to introduce you to your new best friend, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: What about cin >> number[count];

Comment: Don't use `highest` before you've initialised it - have you forgotten to enable plenty of compiler warnings?  Oh, and don't assign to `number[SIZE]` - Valgrind will show you that's out of range.

Answer (score 2):

firstly 
`cin >> number[SIZE];` --> `std::cin >> number[count];`

Secondly `highest` is un-initialized. initialize it with  `number[0]` as

```
highest  = number[0]; /* first time it should have array 0th element value */
for (count =1; count < SIZE; count++) {
    if (number[count] > highest)
        highest = number[count];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> number[SIZE];
```

Should be

```
cin >> number[count];
```

It looks like you misstyped here. What you're actually doing now is reading 10 numbers into the same location into the array. That location is one past the last index of the array you own, resulting undefined behavior. It looks like for you this manifested as a "corrupted stack."

Answer (score 1):

You made a few mistakes. This would be the corrected version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int SIZE = 10;
int number[SIZE];
int count;
int highest;

for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter 10 numbers" << endl;
    cin >> number[count];
    cout << "you entered: " << number[count] << endl;
}

highest = number[0];
for (count = 1; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    if (number[count] > highest)
        highest = number[count];
}

cout << highest << endl;


return 0;
}
```

but consider the following solution, you can simplify and improve your code if you start learning the stl.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter 10 numbers:\n";
    const int size = 10;
    std::vector<int> v(size);
    for (auto& val : v) std::cin >> val;
    std::cout << "max: " << *std::max_element(v.begin(),v.end()) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 Thnx for the tip!